# Unable to build a .Net MVC project in TeamCity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, teamcity

I'm trying to setup a build for a .Net MVC project in TeamCity. I followed the steps described here: [How to build ASPNET applications in TeamCity](http://www.danmusk.com/how-to-build-asp-net-applications-in-teamcity-with-msbuild-tools-2013-and-net-framework-4-5-sdk/)

But the build is still failing. The error messages I have are

```
App_Start\BundleConfig.cs(2, 18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does 

not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 
App_Start\FilterConfig.cs(2, 18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 
App_Start\RouteConfig.cs(5, 18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 
Controllers\HomeController.cs(5, 18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 
Controllers\HomeController.cs(9, 35): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Controller' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
Global.asax.cs(5, 18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 
Global.asax.cs(6, 18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 
App_Start\BundleConfig.cs(9, 44): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BundleCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
App_Start\FilterConfig.cs(8, 50): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'GlobalFilterCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
Controllers\HomeController.cs(11, 16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
Controllers\HomeController.cs(16, 16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
Controllers\HomeController.cs(23, 16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have all the references with Copy Local = true and True in the csproj. TeamCity is downloading correctly the nuget packages but it seems that is not using them. All I can see is that in the .csprojResolveAssemblyReference file in obj/Release there is the following line:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Web.dll

So, it seems that is using that file and not the file in the nuget folder.

What do I have to do to have the build up and running?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I have this exact same problem, but with TFS instead of TeamCity, so I'd be interested in seeing what the possible solution is to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved the problem. What I did is to upload the NuGet packages to the source code repository and remove the NuGet step in the TeamCity configuration. Actually, I prefer this option to be able to work in my code although NuGet was down.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a step to your build process to restore all NuGet packages.
See [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/08/nuget-package-restore-with-teamcity/) for instructions.

Answer (score 1):

[System.Web.Optimization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.bundle(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace is not in the System.Web.dll assembly. It's got its own assembly, System.Web.Optimization.dll. Add that DLL as a reference. If you don't have that DLL, get it via NuGet. I think [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/) is the correct package.

Comment: I have System.Web.Mvc and System.Web.Optimiztion referenced via NuGet, and TeamCity is dowloading both packages. I don't understand why it doesn't look for them in the packages folder.

Comment: Try copying the DLL's manually to the bin folder. I've had it fail to do it automatically before.

Comment: No luck. I think I'm going to re-install the machine and try again.